# Capacity report in mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to have the utilization data for the circuits in Database .For example If I have 100 circuits and utilization data of 6 columns for every month ,Is it good to have 1 table for evry month or increase the no of columns evry month

Comment: Show us your table structure and the query you want to run, so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: it sounds like you are very new to database design. A good reference to read is *Database Design for Mere Mortals*. http://www.amazon.com/Database-Design-Mere-Mortals-Hands-/dp/0201752840/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1344866111&sr=1-2

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your table structure is - one table for every month is really bad design. Add a date or a month field to your table instead.